# Can't find MacVim after mavericks upgrade

Tags: path, xcode5, osx-mavericks, macvim

I upgraded to Mavericks shortly after the release but did not have occasion to use terminal until yesterday and found that nothing worked.  So I installed xcode 5 but 'whereis MacVim' returns nothing.  This may provide clues:

***10:24:36 502 ~/work>echo $PATH
/Developer/Tools:/Developer/Applications:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/jimslager/bin::
***10:24:56 503 ~/work>MacVim
-bash: MacVim: command not found

Comment: The Answer Your Question button isn't working for me so I will answer my question in this comment.  I looked around and found that I should upgrade MacVim to 7.4 and I did that here: https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/releases/tag/snapshot-72